A TV show about a fotoreporter involved in "strange" adventures?
A TV show about a fotoreporter involved in "strange" adventures. By strange, I mean to be in the wrong place at the right moment.
The main clue is that in the opening credits, the voiceover of the main character says:

19XX in a civil jet crashes all passengers die except one, myself.

While the video shows through the thousands of aircraft scrap a 5 year old child sitting and unharmed.
This TV series is set in a U.S. city, tells the adventures of a photojournalist (uses a camera Leica). He happens to be in the wrong place at the right moment to survive and sometime to  take a picture.
Not animated.

Strange Luck maybe?

Having survived a plane crash as a child in which all aboard, including his mother, perished, Chance Harper's every decision leads to incredible displays of luck, both good and bad.
Chance tries to cope with the everyday results of his 'luck' with the help of his close circle of friends and the hope that someday he will find his long-lost brother, mysteriously taken away from his family shortly before the fatal accident. 

 Image Source
Here you can listen to an audio version of the intro.
